# Синхронное перемещение view элементов, при изменении у одного из них высоты

Tags: android, android-sdk

Всем привет. Как можно совершить такой маневр: есть linerlayout, в нем несколько view. У одного из них я хочу изменить высоту. Когда я это делаю, то view ниже того, у которого я меняю размер, смещаются вниз без анимации, при этом view, у которого я изменяю height, изменяется плавно. По идее, эту проблему должен решить coordinatorlayout, но пока это не удалось. Есть ли стандартные средства для моей задачи, или придется вручную писать поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так, постепенно, менять высоту вьюхи. Так, по идее, все нижележащие вьюхи будут смещаться вниз также плавно:

```
 public static void expand(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight) {
    int prevHeight = v.getHeight();

    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevHeight, targetHeight);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        v.requestLayout();
    });
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо!